# Troubleshooting- Something is wrong with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, gwt

I cant figure out what! 
     when you click submit nothing happens, no error, nothing which makes it hard to diagnose,

Any thoughts? here is the code snippet

PS thanks to earlier poster for help posting this correctly

```
<tr>
<td>Image File</td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="uploadedFile" class="gwt-FileUpload">
</td>

</ol></div>
                <div style="width: 100%; display: block; float: right;">
                    <button id="send" type="submit">
                        Send
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postToGoogle() {
                var field1 = $("input[type='radio'][name='qs1']:checked").val();
                var field2 = $("input[type='radio'][name='qs2']:checked").val();
                var field3 = $('#feed').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jkIpSFH16SiNlsj13cBBRsuoiXmqeGVAI6PttCQiff8/formResponse",
                    data: {"entry.1023121230": field3, "entry.1230072460": field1, "entry.2113237615": field2},
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    statusCode: {
                        0: function() {
                            //Success message
                        },
                        200: function() {
                            //Success Message
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#form').submit(function() {
                    postToGoogle();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Progress!! ok, I have been able to ascertain that I am in fact poting to the google spreadsheet simply not showing a response like thanks for your submission etc.

Comment: Also the headings are incorrect, is there some way to replace the var field radio button inputs with the question title for example???

Comment: I don't see any opening tag `<form>` for your form, only a closing tag. Is that maybe the problem?

Comment: have you checked to see what status code you get back from google? It will only carry out the statusCode[200] callback if it receives a 200 otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: wilt: yes there is a opening tag but i didnt include the top half of the form just to keep it simple, im happy to include more if that would help

Comment: franz sittampalam: that is a new thought to me, how would i check that? and if not how will i correct it?

Comment: franz sittampalam: i got a 200 OK response

Comment: OK now i see we are posting and my status is good, However only the timestamp is posting, none of the data is posting. Also still no success screen!! HELP